# How to Block Spam on Server from Certain Service Providers

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, spam, spam-filter, filter

I host my blog on a hosted VM - I am in control of the server. Right now, my blog is getting massive amounts of spam from Ubiquity Server Solutions (aka Nobis Technology Group). I've identified this provider via Google Analytics.

Apparently I'm not the only one this is happening to:

http://cogdogblog.com/2010/03/28/spam-supporters-ubiquity-hosting/

I'm a total newbie when it comes to admin - can anyone give me some simple steps to mitigate against this flood of spam I'm getting (500/600 some days)? And could this affect my SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to block their IP ranges via your server's firewall, but that will also block legit traffic, which may or may not be a big deal for you. Alternatively, you can look into integrating one of several content-analysis engines out there that will screen posts and classify them as spam (or not) before they get posted. [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) and [Mollom](http://mollom.com/) are two of the most popular ones. Another option would be to integrate a captcha in your posting dialogue, say [Re-captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for instance.

Comment: Actually, I'm in the process of upgrading my instance of BlogEngine - the newer version includes Akismet and RECAPTACHA. In the meantime, I was thinking  of blocking some of the offending IP ranges and wasn't sure of the steps to do this...

Comment: That's really a separate topic. Search for posts dealing with the Windows Server 2008 firewall. There are probably several around. If not, ask a separate question about how to go about adding firewall rules.